# QML Javascript "console.log" with UTF-8

Tags: javascript, string, qt, utf-8, qml

As we all know that in QML Javascript we can log to console by calling the 'console.log' function.

However, as per my experience, I can't log UTF-8 strings to console that the strings are still in proper characters, some are replaced by question marks.

For example:

```
console.log("XXXaàáảãạYYY");
```

will become (in console):

```
XXX??????YYY
```

How to solve this problem? I know console is just for debugging so I can use latin, but anyway, full UTF-8 support would be more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

My console show them just fine.

I guess the problem is not about QML, but your console can't handle those UTF-8 characters.